# ImageFilledArc fails under PHP 5.x

Tags: php

I have a complex piece of PHP which uses ImageFilledArc to draw a 2-stroke engine timing diagram. It has worked for years under php 5.2 but my ISP has upgraded the server to PHP 5.3 and the arcs are no longer rendered. The image below shows what happens, and what was expected.

[image]

Tests show the function is returning FAIL (zero) to all values of 'style'. Experiments show ImageFilledRectangle works as expected (code inserted into the program so it uses the same target GD image instance and color values).

Web searches have failed to find any mention of changes to any graphic functions in the PHP transition document, nor anyone else having problems with this function. The code which draws the graphics is provided below. The code which calls it is not, but it can be tested by calling the page with no args at all.

```
<?php
/*
 * Creats a PNG image of the MBI CAD standard timing 2-stroke diagram.
 *
 * Created on Aug 10, 2007 by Ronald A Chernich, Brisbane, Australia.
 * This work is licensed under the Creative Commons
 * Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 license.
 * See: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0
 *
 * 2007-08-08 1.0   First version
 * 2007-08-13 1.1   Add FRV labeling adjustment
 * 2007-08-15 1.2   Add SPI capability and blow-down
 * 2007-08-15 1.2.1 Revise SPI representation to Inlet side of graph
 * 2007-08-25 1.2.2 SPI and inlet labels overlapped in some cases. Fixed.
 */

  $eo = $_GET['eo'];
  $to = $_GET['to'];
  $ic = $_GET['ic'];
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $nm = $_GET['nm'];
  $spi = $_GET['spi'];

  // Test data for development
  if (empty($nm)) {
    $nm = 'Test';
    $eo = 108;
    $to = 123;
    $ic = 15;
    $id = 140;
  }

  $graph = new TimingDiagram($nm, $eo, $to, $ic, $id, $spi);
  $graph->render();

/**
 * Class to render image
 */
class TimingDiagram
{
    var $WIDTH = 420;
    var $HEIGHT = 420;
    var $YMARGIN = 30;
    var $XMIN = 2;
    var $YMIN = 2;

    var $BG_COLOR;
    var $IN_COLOR;
    var $TR_COLOR;
    var $EX_COLOR;
    var $LAP_COLOR;
    var $AXIS_COLOR;
    var $TITLE_COLOR;

    var $image;

    var $eo;
    var $to;
    var $ic;
    var $id;
    var $spi;
    var $arc;
    var $title;
    var $degChar;

    function TimingDiagram ($title, $eo, $to, $ic, $id, $spi)
    {
      $this->title = $title;
      $this->eo = $eo;
      $this->to = $to;
      $this->ic = $ic;
      $this->id = $id;
      $this->spi = $spi;

      $this->degChar = '°';
      $this->image = ImageCreateTruecolor($this->WIDTH, $this->HEIGHT);
      $this->InitColors();

      $this->arc_y = $this->HEIGHT / 12;

      $xmax = $this->WIDTH - (2 * $this->XMIN);
      $ymax = $this->HEIGHT - (2 * $this->YMIN);
      ImageFilledRectangle($this->image, $this->XMIN, $this->YMIN,
                           $xmax, $ymax, $this->BG_COLOR);
    }

    function initColors ()
    {
      $this->BG_COLOR = ImageColorAllocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
      $this->TITLE_COLOR = ImageColorAllocate($this->image, 0, 0, 120);
      $this->AXIS_COLOR = ImageColorAllocate($this->image, 200, 200, 200);

      $this->IN_COLOR = ImageColorAllocate($this->image, 180, 180, 180);
      $this->TR_COLOR = ImageColorAllocate($this->image, 120, 120, 120);
      $this->EX_COLOR = ImageColorAllocate($this->image, 80, 80, 80);
      $this->LAP_COLOR = ImageColorAllocate($this->image, 140, 140, 140);
    }

    function render ()
    {
      $x0 = $this->WIDTH  / 2;
      $y0 = $this->HEIGHT  / 2;
      $this->drawTitle($x0, $y0);
      $this->drawSPI($x0, $y0);
      $this->drawExhaust($x0, $y0);
      $this->drawInlet($x0, $y0);
      $this->drawSPI($x0, $y0);
      $this->drawTransfer($x0, $y0);
      $this->drawRot($x0, $y0);
      Header("Content-type: image/png");
      ImagePng($this->image);
      ImageDestroy($this->image);
    }

    function drawTitle ()
    {
      $st = "Timing Diagram for $this->title.";
      $fnt = 5;
      $dx = ($this->WIDTH - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($st))) / 2;
      $dy = ($this->YMARGIN - ImageFontHeight($fnt)) / 2;
      imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $dy, $st, $this->TITLE_COLOR);
    }

    function drawSPI ($x0, $y0)
    {
      if (is_numeric($this->spi)) {
        $end = 270 - $this->spi;
        $start = 270 + $this->spi;
        $dx1 = .64 * $this->WIDTH;
        $dy1 = .64 * $this->HEIGHT;
        $dim = $this->arc_y * .75;
        $dx2 = $dx1 - $dim;
        $dy2 = $dy1 - $dim;
        ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx1, $dy1, $end, $start,
                       $this->IN_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);
        $res = ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx2, $dy2, $end-1, $start+1,
                       $this->BG_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);

        $x = $this->WIDTH * 0.1;
        $y = $this->HEIGHT * (($this->ic > 29) ? 0.3 : 0.2);
        $this->labelEvent($x, $y, "SPI ends", "ATDC", $this->spi);
        $this->labelEvent($this->WIDTH - $x, $y, "SPI starts", "ABDC",
                         (180 - $this->spi));
        // Drawing SPI will have trashed the Inlet duration label
        $fnt = 3;
        $id = (empty($this->id) ? (2 * $this->ic) : $this->id);
        $lab = sprintf('Inlet %.0f%s', $id, $this->degChar);
        $dx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab)) / 2);
        $dy = ($y0 - (.22 * $this->HEIGHT) - ImageFontHeight($fnt));
        Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $dy, $lab, $this->TITLE_COLOR);
        $lab = sprintf('with %.0f%s', $this->spi * 2, $this->degChar);
        $dy += ImageFontHeight($fnt);
        $dx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab)) / 2);
        Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $dy, $lab, $this->TITLE_COLOR);
        $lab = 'sub-piston induction';
        $dy += ImageFontHeight($fnt);
        $dx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab)) / 2);
        Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $dy, $lab, $this->TITLE_COLOR);
      }
    }

    function drawExhaust ($x0, $y0)
    {
      if ($this->eo > 0) {
        $ex = 180 - $this->eo;
        $eo = 90 + $ex;
        $ec = 90 - $ex;
        $dx1 = .8 * $this->WIDTH;
        $dy1 = .8 * $this->HEIGHT;
        $dx2 = $dx1 - $this->arc_y;
        $dy2 = $dy1 - $this->arc_y;
        ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx1, $dy1, $ec, $eo,
                       $this->EX_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);
        ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx2, $dy2, $ec-1, $eo+1,
                       $this->BG_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);

        $fnt = 3;
        $lab = sprintf('Exhaust %.0f%s', (2 * $ex), $this->degChar);
        $dx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab)) / 2);
        $dy = ($y0 + (.46 * $this->HEIGHT) - ImageFontHeight($fnt));
        Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $dy, $lab, $this->TITLE_COLOR);

        $x = $this->WIDTH * 0.12;
        $y = $this->HEIGHT * 0.86;
        $this->labelEvent($x, $y, "Exhaust opens", "ATDC", $this->eo);
        $this->labelEvent($this->WIDTH - $x, $y, "Exhaust closes", "ABDC",
                          180 - $this->eo);
      }
    }

    function drawTransfer ($x0, $y0)
    {
      if ($this->to > 0) {
        $tr = 180 - $this->to;
        $to = 90 + $tr;
        $tc = 90 - $tr;
        $dx1 = .7 * $this->WIDTH;
        $dy1 = .7 * $this->HEIGHT;
        $dx2 = $dx1 - $this->arc_y;
        $dy2 = $dy1 - $this->arc_y;
        ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx1, $dy1, $tc, $to,
                       $this->TR_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);
        ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx2, $dy2, $tc-1, $to+1,
                       $this->BG_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);

        // Special case where FRV inlet overlaps transfer close
        if (!empty($this->id)) {
          $io = ($this->id - $this->ic) - 90;
          if ($io > $tc) {
            ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx1, $dy1, $tc, $io,
                           $this->LAP_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);
            ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx2, $dy2, $tc-1, $io+1,
                           $this->BG_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);
          }
        }
        $fnt = 3;
        $lab = sprintf('Transfer %.0f%s', (2 * $tr), $this->degChar);
        $dx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab)) / 2);
        $dy = ($y0 + (.25 * $this->HEIGHT) - ImageFontHeight($fnt));
        Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $dy, $lab, $this->TITLE_COLOR);

        $x = $this->WIDTH * 0.35;
        $y = $this->HEIGHT * 0.65;
        $this->labelEvent($x, $y, "Transfer opens", "ATDC", $this->to);
        $this->labelEvent($this->WIDTH - $x, $y, "Transfer closes", "ABDC",
                          180 - $this->to);
      }
    }

    function drawInlet ($x0, $y0)
    {
      if (is_numeric($this->ic)) {
        $ic = 270 - $this->ic;
        $id = (is_numeric($this->id) ? $this->id : 2 * $this->ic);
        $io = $ic + $id;
        $dx1 = .7 * $this->WIDTH;
        $dy1 = .7 * $this->HEIGHT;
        $dx2 = $dx1 - $this->arc_y;
        $dy2 = $dy1 - $this->arc_y;
        ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx1, $dy1, $ic, $io,
                       $this->IN_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);
        ImageFilledArc($this->image, $x0, $y0, $dx2, $dy2, $ic-2, $io+2,
                       $this->BG_COLOR, IMAGE_ARC_PIE);

        $fnt = 3;
        $id = (empty($this->id) ? (2 * $this->ic) : $this->id);
        $lab = sprintf('Inlet %.0f%s', $id, $this->degChar);
        $dx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab)) / 2);
        $dy = ($y0 - (.22 * $this->HEIGHT) - ImageFontHeight($fnt));
        Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $dy, $lab, $this->TITLE_COLOR);

        $x = $this->WIDTH * 0.13;
        $y = $this->HEIGHT * 0.2;
        $isBTDC = $this->ic < 0;
        $tag = $isBTDC ? 'BTDC' : 'ATDC';
        if ($isBTDC || ($this->ic < 30)) {
          $x = $this->WIDTH -
               ($isBTDC ? ($this->WIDTH * 0.3) : ($this->WIDTH * 0.65));
          $y = $this->HEIGHT * 0.12;
        }
        $this->labelEvent($x, $y, "Inlet closes", $tag, abs($this->ic));

        $x = $this->WIDTH * 0.13;
        $y = $this->HEIGHT * 0.2;
        if ($isBTDC || ($this->ic < 30)) {
        $x = $this->WIDTH * 0.1;
          $y = $this->HEIGHT * 0.3;
        }
        $tmp = (is_numeric($this->id)) ? ($this->id - $this->ic) : $this->ic;
        $this->labelEvent($this->WIDTH-$x, $y, "Inlet opens", "ABDC", 180-$tmp);
      }
    }

    function labelEvent ($x0, $y0, $lab1, $st2, $angle)
    {
      $fnt = 2;
      $dx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab1)) / 2);
      $dy = $y0 - ImageFontHeight($fnt);
      Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $dy, $lab1, $this->TITLE_COLOR);
      $lab2 = sprintf('%.1f%s %s', $angle, $this->degChar, $st2);
      $dx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab2)) / 2);
      Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $dx, $y0, $lab2, $this->TITLE_COLOR);
    }

    function drawRot ($x0, $y0)
    {
      $xtick = $this->WIDTH / 30;
      ImageLine($this->image,
                $x0 - $xtick, $y0, $x0 + $xtick, $y0,
                $this->AXIS_COLOR);
      $ytick = $this->HEIGHT / 28;
      ImageLine($this->image,
                $x0, $y0 + $ytick, $x0, $y0 - (2 * $ytick),
                $this->AXIS_COLOR);
      $xrad = $this->WIDTH / 8;
      $yrad = $this->HEIGHT / 8;
      ImageArc($this->image,
               $x0, $y0, $xrad, $yrad, 270, 180, $this->AXIS_COLOR);
      $ahx = $xrad / 8;
      $ahy = $yrad / 15;
      $dy = ($yrad / 2) - ($ahy / 2);
      $points = array(($x0 - $ahx), ($y0 - $dy),
                      ($x0 + $ahx), ($y0 - $dy - $ahy),
                      ($x0 + $ahx), ($y0 - $dy + $ahy),
                      ($x0 - $ahx), ($y0 - $dy));
      ImageFilledPolygon($this->image, $points, 4, $this->AXIS_COLOR);
      $lab = "TDC";
      $fnt = 3;
      $tx = ($x0 - (ImageFontWidth($fnt) * strlen($lab)) / 2);
      $ty = ($y0 - ( .6 * $yrad) - ImageFontHeight($fnt));
      Imagestring($this->image, $fnt, $tx, $ty, $lab, $this->TITLE_COLOR);

      if (($this->eo > 0) && ($this->to> 0) ) {
        $x = $this->WIDTH * 0.092;
        $y = $this->HEIGHT * 0.93;

        $this->labelEvent($x, $y, 'Blowdown:', '', ($this->to - $this->eo));
      }
    }

}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.imagefilledarc.php), they use **IMG_ARC_PIE** and not **IMAGE_ARC_PIE**.

I try after replacement with PHP 5.3.8 and I get this result :
[image]

Comment: Brilliant.  I looked at the doco for hours yesterday and didn't see that change.  Thanks.